# Two HDD installation

Tags: debian, system-installation, hard-disk, ssd

Is there any easy tutorial or guide how can I setup Debian (amd64 v. 7 + xface) on my server, but using this separation ?

**Separation:**

- SSD (32GB) for system
- Normal HDD (1TB) for data like /var ...

Comment: Questions seeking learning material recommendations (like tutorials) are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: You do this exactly the same way you handle multiple partitions on a single hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure why you would need a dedicated tutorial for that. In such an easy case as described above, it is enough to format both disks and simply put `/` on the SSD. Your normal HDD would then be mounted into `/var`.

You can use the Debian installer to arrange this, although you might want to reconsider your scheme, because `/var` is not necessarily containing most of the data on a typical desktop system.

Furthermore it makes separate a few directories (such as `/home`) in order to be able keep things across different installations. For reasons of security (i.e. full disk encryption) it might also make sense to have at least another partition for `/boot`. Having `/tmp` reside in another partition (or even better using tmpfs) might also make a lot of sense. There is more than one way to skin this cow, so you should put some thoughts into this beforehand, because in general it is rather inconvenient to change these things later on.

By the way: Also consider to make use of [LVM](https://wiki.debian.org/LVM) in order to be more flexible in the future.